# Does Hogwarts have its own anthem?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Does *Hogwarts* have its own anthem or song? If yes, what are the lyrics of that song?

I want to know if anything about a song or anthem is mentioned in the books.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As seen in the book *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Hogwarts has a [school song](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/the-hogwarts-song).

> Hogwarts, Hogwarts, Hoggy Warty Hogwarts,
>   Teach us something please,
>   Whether we be old and bald
>   Or young with scabby knees,
>   Our heads could do with filling
>   With some interesting stuff,
>   For now they’re bare and full of air,
>   Dead flies and bits of fluff,
>   So teach us things worth knowing,
>   Bring back what we’ve forgot,
>   Just do your best, we’ll do the rest,
>   And learn until our brains all rot.

It's sung to whatever tune you want, at whatever volume you please, and presumably sounds horrible.

> ‘Everyone pick their favourite tune,’ said Dumbledore, ‘and off we go!’
>   And the school bellowed:

There's also a distinct lack of meter.

> Everybody finished the song at different times. At last, only the Weasley twins were left singing along to a very slow funeral march. Dumbledore conducted their last few lines with his wand, and when they had finished, he was one of those who clapped loudest.

---

The song appears (almost in full) in a deleted scene in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*.

And the first couple of lines made it into the same film.