# Does each house in Hogwarts have its own anthem?

Tags: harry-potter

After seeing this question: [Does Hogwarts have its own anthem?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/does-hogwarts-have-its-own-anthem)

**I was wondering if each house in Hogwarts has its own anthem?** I know Slytherin wrote the song "Weasley is our King" but can we consider it as an anthem? 
In my opinion I don't think it is but I'm wondering a bit about this.

Answer (score 4):

No, "Weasley is our King" is not an anthem, not for Slytherin and not for Gryffindor.

It is just a text created by Malfoy (and maybe others) to make fun of Ron Weasley, to make him nervous and create a self fulfilling prophecy that makes him play badly, helping Slytherin to win the game. It's nothing that would make sense to use a few years later when Ron is no longer the keeper.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no indication in the books that each, or any of the houses, have their own songs or anthems.

Only the school song, as discussed in the [linked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/does-hogwarts-have-its-own-anthem?noredirect=1&lq=1) question is referenced.